# Installing Perl module in Unix

Tags: perl, perl-module, dbi

This is my first time installing a Perl module and I'm having some trouble. I'm trying to install manually In UNIX. These are the steps I am following (Installing DBI module in this case)

1. Download DBI-1.628.tar.gz tar file,
2. Uncompress file with

   `$ tar -zxvf DBI-1.628.tar.gz`

So far no problems,
Its the next step that is confusing me... In every tutorial I've seen so far I'm told to locate `Makefile.PL` then run the following commands:

```
$ perl Makefile.PL
$ make
$ make test
$ make install
```

In my case, after locating `Makefile.PL` and running

```
$ perl Makefile.PL
```

...some output follows. I get these messages
    `Checking if your kit is complete... Looks good` & `Writing Makefile for DBI`

Then I'm back in my user command prompt. Note I still haven't entered these commands

```
$ make
$ make test
$ make install
```

From the command prompt if I enter the `make` command now I get a `-bash: make: command not found` error.

I'm an absolute beginner at this so please excuse me If I am missing something rudimentary.

Comment: What is "Unix" in your case? It is is Linux, just about every distribution will have the Perl DBI module packaged for you.  In any event, `make: command not found` means you do not even have `make` binary installed.

Comment: If you don't have `make` installed, then you probably don't have a unix configured for software development. You'll have to install a full suite of build tools. compiler, linker, etc...

Comment: Im using terminal in mac OSX and Im using the preinstalled version of perl. maybe I should update first?

Comment: Are there any software development Kits you would recommend for terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using MAC OSX, just fire up a terminal and type 'cpan'.  Allow it to configure automatically and do some stuff, then you can install modules by just typing `install Your::Module::Name`.  To get out of cpan just hit ctrl-c or type `quit`.

You can also install directly from the command line by using `cpan -i 'Your::Module::Name'`.

NB: You may need to type `sudo cpan` and put in your password rather than just cpan on it's own depending how your mac is configured.

Simply to get the `make` command on a mac, you need to go to the app store and install the latest version of XCode, then turn on the 'command line utilities' option.  See more on that here: [Xcode 4.4 and later install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools)

Comment: Until you get to the final paragraph, your advice doesn't seem to be Mac-specific at all. It will work for any Unix-like operating system.

Comment: @DaveCross is right. The final paragraph is the answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks. XCode Command Line Utilities worked perfectly. Should I be worried about the Skipped tests during the `$ make test` command?

Comment: @BryanK no, the distribution knows which tests to skip based on your environment. You should be worried if tests fail, though.

Comment: @BryanK also, in the future, use a CPAN client like the `cpan` commandline utility to download modules; it will handle dependencies for you automatically. [`cpanm`](https://raw.github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus/master/cpanm) is a lot easier to use (follow the instructions there to install it.)

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to install perl modules is using cpan, which should be included on your system.

For example:
`cpan DBI`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get Perl modules installed is to use the CPAN module itself.

Run the Perl CPAN module via command line perl and get it installed in a single line:

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Module::Name'
```

If you have login as a root user, do not use `sudo`.