# Missing OpenGL headers on mac

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl

I am trying to use OpenGL in mac, but when I am including the glut header, It includes the OpenGL one an then It's not able to find the `OpenGL/gl.h` header.
I have looked the problem up in the internet, and It seems that this files should be inside the `/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers` directory, but such subdirectory does not exist. I have tried reinstalling XCode and didn't work.

Any suggestions of how should I proceed.

**Some specifics:**
here is what `/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current`  looks like:

```
localhost@Current$ ls -la
total 368
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel     238 Oct  7  2012 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel     136 Oct  7  2012 ..
drwxr-xr-x  16 root  wheel     544 Oct  7  2012 Libraries
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  185184 Oct  3  2012 OpenGL
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel     102 Jun 16  2011 PlugIns
drwxr-xr-x  14 root  wheel     476 Oct  7  2012 Resources
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel     102 Oct  7  2012 _CodeSignature
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For everyone else who is having this problem, the solution is fairly easy. The problem is that probably not all the command line tools are installed, so the key is to install them. You just need to follow what is suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools) post and install all the command line tools that are missing. Then you'll have a beautiful OpenGL hello world running smoothly :D :D

Comment: You should probably `Accept` this answer so people don't think the issue is still unresolved ;)

Answer (score 6):

In mavericks (10.9), these got moved.  The stuff in /System/Library/Frameworks no longer has any development headers; it seems to be purely a deployment build of the frameworks.  So, Andés is right - he's looking exactly where he was told to look, but the files he's looking for *simply aren't there*.

Instead, XCode itself stores these as part of its install - XCode comes with multiple SDKs for various versions of OS X, and inside these, there are the headers for these libraries.  For example:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers/

Answer (score 0):

On all of my OS X development machines, I have: `/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers`

I even have SDKs for targeted versions:

> /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers/gl.h
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers/gl.h
>
> ...

```
[ andon@Aleph : ~ ] ls -lA "/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers"
total 1464
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   557B Mar  3  2010 CGLContext.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   381B Mar  3  2010 CGLCurrent.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   389B Mar  3  2010 CGLDevice.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    14K Mar  3  2010 CGLIOSurface.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   128K Mar  3  2010 CGLMacro.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   6.4K Feb 12  2011 CGLProfiler.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    28K Feb 12  2011 CGLProfilerFunctionEnum.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1.5K Mar  3  2010 CGLRenderers.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    14K Mar  3  2010 CGLTypes.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   5.6K Mar  3  2010 OpenGL.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   151K Mar  3  2010 gl.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   267K Mar  3  2010 glext.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   328B Mar  3  2010 gliContext.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    63K Mar  3  2010 gliDispatch.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    16K Mar  3  2010 glu.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   2.6K Mar  3  2010 gluContext.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   2.2K Mar  3  2010 gluMacro.h
```

Regardless where the file is, the fact that it's in `.../Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/...` is an indication that you need to add `-framework OpenGL` to your compiler/linker switches for includes and libraries to be located correctly.

Comment: I am not sure. I installed XCode a while ago, then, when reinstalling it again, it did not ask for this options. I'm gonna look into a little deeper. Thank you. BTW, there is no Headers directory in OpenGL.Frameworks/..

Comment: @Andrés: There shouldn't be one to begin with - It should be `OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers` which is really a symlink to `OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers` most of the time.

Comment: look at the updated question. There is no such subdirectory anywhere inside the OpenGL.framework/ directory.

Comment: @Andrés: I'm all out of ideas. They must have changed something in Xcode since version 4.0. The last thing I can think of is `ls -lAr "/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/"` Maybe you have multiple versions or something, one for binary distribution and one for compiling?