# my refractored titanium module won't build

Tags: titanium, titanium-modules

I had a working titanium module but i went to refractor it and suddenly i get this error when trying to package it:

```
Executing build.xml...
/Users/elidd1/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.2.GA/module/android/build.xml:326: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/elidd1/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.2.GA/module/android/build.xml:281: exec returned: 2 You may need to install the Command Line Tools package through XCode, in case you haven't done so yet.
```

anyone know why?  i used the refractor tool built into titanium

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install xCode command line tools. You can find in this thread how to do.

[Xcode 4.4 and later install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools)