# How to execute and compile a program in Xcode via command line in c and where's the executable?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, xcode4

I'm trying to execute via command line a code written in C. I tried gcc -o file file.c, but it did not work. I need to learn how to compile and execute a code using gcc and llvm without graphical interface. Furthermore when I compile the program I cannot find the executable file in Finder (there's no Developer folder in Library).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "it did not work" mean, exactly? Any errors or warnings? Was "file" produced in the current directory, or not?

Comment: @KurtRevis It appears "gcc: command not found".

Comment: Did you [install the Xcode command-line tools](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/1218876) yet?

Comment: @KurtRevis No, I'm installing now. Hope it works.

Comment: @KurtRevis It appears "no input files" (with gcc), however the file is in Desktop. Furthermore, when I try using "llvm -o file file.c", it appears "llvm : command not found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xcrun tool:

```
#/usr/bin/xcrun cc -o file file.c
```

Note: if you have several Xcode versions you can chose with xcode-select and your command above will use compiler and the rest of the tools from the selected SDK.

Answer (score 1):

If file.c is in the Desktop directory: Did you change to that directory beforehand?

Usually Terminal.app starts in the home directory, e.g.: /Users/yourname

To get to the Desktop directory:

> cd ~/Desktop

Then check if the source file is there:

> ls -l file.c

Then try again to compile:

> gcc -o file file.c

Check for any error messages. If no output is given everything is fine and there should be an executable which can be (surprise!) executed:

```
ls -l file
 ./file
```