# python: attempt to install the python-twitter causing error

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I am trying to install the twitter module on my python and for some unknown reason it is keep throwing an error message.
I use Macbook and on terminal I typed:

```
pip install python-twitter
```

and then it seems to work for awhile but then error says:

```
SystemError: Cannot locate working compiler
```

??? why is this error popping up and is there anyway to resolve it?

thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the message says you need a working compiler. Presumably `python-twitter` uses C extensions that must be compiled.

Easiest way is to install XCode and then install the "Command line tools"

See this answer: [Xcode 4.4 and later install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools)