# ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o after running Intel icc compiler on OS Mavericks

Tags: macos, compiler-warnings, icc

I just upgraded from OS Mountain Lion to Mavericks, ran intel icc compiler, `icc test.c`, it said `#include <time.h>` is not found. So I checked the `\usr` folder, found `\usr\include` is missing and copyed `include` from my back to this folder, upgraded Xcode to Version 5.0.1. Then I compilered it again but still got a warning

```
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o
```

What does it mean? How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed command line tool for Mavericks, now it fixes the problem!

For more detail, refer to [this link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2252567/).

Comment: Bryce has the better link

Answer (score 10):

I got a similar compiler error when installing MacPorts' mysql5 (missing lcrt).  Jared Burrows is correct.  The quickie way to do this is to open Terminal and enter:

```
xcode-select --install
```

I'm not sure the discussions.apple.com link is much help.  Just seemed to be a bunch of folks arguing over whether static linking was 'sometimes ok' or 'bad programmer, no cookie.'

But here's a related Stack question, if mine doesn't work: [Xcode 4.4 and later install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools/)

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue while having the set 'Build Active Architecture Only' to 'No' for all configurations in build settings.
Set this for 'debug' (my current local configuration I am building with on device) to 'YES' solved the problem for me.