# Ruby on Rails : FFMPEG fails after upgrade Mountain Lion to Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ffmpeg, osx-mavericks

yesterday I upgrade my OS fom Mountain Lion to Mavericks and all goes well until recently.

We are developing a Ruby on Rails v3.2.13 application for manage videos (only MP4), which worked fine until yesterday with Mountain Lion. Today (with Mavericks) I try to upload a video but get the following error in the console:

```
Running transcoding...
ffmpeg -y -i /Users/ME/Documents/workspace/rails/rails3-devise/public/uploads/tmp/1382653048-574-3293/thumb_con02_apv_revisado_1280x720.mp4 -ss 0 -s 180x110 -vframes 1 -f image2 -aspect 1.6363636363636365 /Users/Me/Documents/workspace/rails/rails3-devise/public/uploads/tmp/1382653048-574-3293/thumb_con02_apv_revisado_1280x720.png

Transcoding of /Users/Me/Documents/workspace/rails/rails3-devise/public/uploads/tmp/1382653048-574-3293/thumb_con02_apv_revisado_1280x720.mp4 to /Users/Me/Documents/workspace/railspublic/uploads/tmp/1382653048-574-3293/thumb_con02_apv_revisado_1280x720.png succeeded

Running transcoding...
ffmpeg -y -i /Users/Me/Documents/workspace/rails/public/uploads/tmp/1382653048-574-3293/thumb_con02_apv_revisado_1280x720.mp4 -ss 0 -s 180x110 -vframes 1 -f image2 -aspect 1.6363636363636365 /Users/Me/Documents/workspace/rails/rails3-devise/public/uploads/tmp/1382653048-574-3293/thumb_con02_apv_revisado_1280x720.png

Failed encoding...
ffmpeg -y -i /Users/Me/Documents/workspace/rails/tmp/1382653048-574-3293/thumb_con02_apv_revisado_1280x720.mp4 -ss 0 -s 180x110 -vframes 1 -f image2 -aspect 1.6363636363636365 /Users/Me/Documents/workspace/rails/uploads/tmp/1382653048-574-3293/thumb_con02_apv_revisado_1280x720.png

ffmpeg version 1.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Sep 28 2013 20:09:07 with Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.24) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/1.2.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=cc --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libspeex --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-frei0r --enable-libopenjpeg --extra-cflags='-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/1.5.1/include/openjpeg-1.5 '
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[mp3 @ 0x7fd493820c00] Format mp3 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mp3 @ 0x7fd49380a000] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mp3 @ 0x7fd493820c00] decoding for stream 0 failed
[mp3 @ 0x7fd493820c00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Audio: mp2, 0 channels, s16p): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mp3 @ 0x7fd493820c00] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
/Users/Me/Documents/workspace/rails/tmp/1382653048-574-3293/thumb_con02_apv_revisado_1280x720.mp4: could not find codec parameters

Errors: no output file created.
```

I reinstall the dependencies of ffmpeg, but the problem persists.

Any ideas or suggestions to solve the problem?
Thank you very much!

**EDIT NOTE:** I notice this when run `brew upgrade` :

```
==> Upgrading ffmpeg
==> Installing ffmpeg dependency: libass
Error: libass dependency fontconfig was built with the following
C++ standard library: libstdc++ (from clang)

This is incompatible with the standard library being used
to build libass: libc++ (from clang)

Please reinstall fontconfig using a compatible compiler.
hint: Check https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/C++-Standard-Libraries
```

Comment: Is this the complete console output? Please include the ffmpeg command too.

Comment: Thanks @LordNeckbeard, i edit the post with the full error displayed and new **EDIT NOTE** incorporate.

Comment: Have you upgraded xcode and xcode command line tools?

Comment: Thanks @Sean. Yes i have upgraded xcode at current version 5.0.1 (5A2053)

Comment: Did you upgrade the command line tools too?

Comment: yes, I upgrade the command line tools 5 minutes ago and restart the computer too.. but I have the 2 same problem...

Comment: I notice something, when go to xcode->Preferences->Downloads I don't see the command line tools installed as here say : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools . I only see iphone simulators installed..

Comment: It appears that some of the console output is possibly missing. Do you get a different result if you run the failing command manually?

Comment: I notice a very very strange issue.. Run `rails s` to start Rails and then upload a video  : it fails and show me the error.. But when edit a carrierwave configuration file and remove this changes immediately, its work fine and video upload is success. Example : add a space and then remove it immediately (with Rails working at same time on background).. And the video upload work.. If I try my code in Linux the problem not exist..