# Can't install FFMPEG on OS X Mavericks

Tags: ffmpeg, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I have an error when install FFMPEG through homebrew on OS X Mavericks running this command `brew install ffmpeg` :

```
Error: ffmpeg dependency x264 was built with the following
C++ standard library: libstdc++ (from clang)

This is incompatible with the standard library being used
to build ffmpeg: libc++ (from clang)

Please reinstall x264 using a compatible compiler.
hint: Check https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/C++-Standard-Libraries
```

The complete history is : I has installed FFMPEG on Mountain Lion (that worked fine), but when upgrade it to Mavericks, FFMPEG fails to create an video in my Ruby on Rails app : [Ruby on Rails : FFMPEG fails after upgrade Mountain Lion to Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577364/ruby-on-rails-ffmpeg-fails-after-upgrade-mountain-lion-to-mavericks)

Some idea or recommendation??

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with some packages. In particular, when I tried to install octave. Same error. I'm not sure that the answers you've gotten so far address the issue, though. Sounds like a Mavericks problem.

Comment: Yes! is a Mavericks problem.. Because c++ standard libraries are changed.. So, when install dependencies, the old compiled program is incompatible with the new interpreter. I have formated my HDD with Mavericks (clean install) and all works ok now. Look Mark Essel's answer bellow. More information : https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/C---standard-libraries

Answer (score 4):

As said @CristianOrellanaBak - this is a Mavericks issue: libstdc++ (10.8), libc++ (10.9)

I have created a Git repository, which is a compilation of recommendations to solve this issue https://github.com/xvoland/brew-regenerate-packages

Answer (score 1):

I solve it reinstalling ffmpeg with all dependencies :

- libass
- x264
- fontconfig
- xvid
- libogg
- libvorbis
- theora
- libvpx
- rtmpdump
- opencore-amr
- libvo-aacenc
- libtiff
- little-cms2
- openjpeg
- sdl
- speex
- orc
- schroedinger
- opus
- frei0r

better idea is format the hard disck and do a clean install..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you mixed c++11 and c++98 libs. Check the formulas and make sure they'll all consistent