# Why is the apt-get function not working in the terminal on Mac OS X v10.9 (Mavericks)?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, package-managers

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oT1A1KKf0SI), and, as you can see, the first command I am told to put in is:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

When I do this, it outputs:

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

I have no idea why this is the case.

How can I resolve this so I am following the tutorial correctly?

Answer (score 297):

Mac OS X doesn't have `apt-get`. There is a package manager called [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) that is used instead.

This command would be:

> brew install python

Use Homebrew to install packages that you would otherwise use `apt-get` for.

The page I linked to has an up-to-date way of installing homebrew, but at present, you can install Homebrew as follows:

> Type the following in your Mac OS X terminal:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
> ```

After that, usage of Homebrew is `brew install <package>`.

One of the prerequisites for Homebrew are the XCode command line tools.

1. Install XCode from the App Store.
2. Follow the directions in this [Stack Overflow answer to install the XCode Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools).

#### Background

A package manager (like `apt-get` or `brew`) just gives your system an easy and automated way to install packages or libraries.  Different systems use different programs.  `apt` and its derivatives are used on Debian based linux systems. Red Hat-ish Linux systems use `rpm` (or at least they did many, many, years ago).  `yum` is also a package manager for RedHat based systems.

Alpine based systems use `apk`.

#### Warning

As of 25 April 2016, [homebrew opts the user in to sending analytics by default](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/142). This can be opted out of in two ways:

**Setting an environment variable:**

1. Open your [favorite environment variable editor](https://superuser.com/questions/324616/how-should-i-set-the-path-variable-on-my-mac-so-the-hombrew-installed-tools-are).
2. Set the following: `HOMEBREW_NO_ANALYTICS=1`  in whereever you keep your environment variables (typically something like `~/.bash_profile`)
3. Close the file, and either restart the terminal or `source ~/.bash_profile`.

**Running the following command:**

```
brew analytics off
```

the analytics status can then be checked with the command:

```
brew analytics
```

Comment: @Panique install homebrew or if you have done it, reopen your terminal.

Comment: it's worth noting that Mac OS X is a unix-based OS (Unix -> BSD -> NeXTSTEP -> Mac OS X) :)

Comment: In High Sierra, I still get `sudo: apt-get: command not found` after installing Homebrew. :(

Comment: @jimiayler `apt-get` will never be available via `brew`. You should use `brew install <x>` for whatever you would have written `sudo apt-get install <x>`.

Comment: @refaelio It's not just unix-based, it's Unix / POSIX certified, even Linux isn't so much of a unix as macOS

Comment: FYI Ruby Homebrew installer is being deprecated.  Documentation suggests using this install script instead `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

Answer (score 7):

As *[Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29)* is my favorite for macOS although it is possible to have `apt-get` on macOS using [Fink](http://fink.thetis.ig42.org/download/index.php?phpLang=en).

Answer (score 3):

[MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) is another package manager for OS X:.

Installation instructions are at *[The MacPorts Project -- Download & Installation](https://www.macports.org/install.php)* after which one issues `sudo port install pythonXX`, where `XX` is `27` or `35`.

Answer (score 3):

`apt-get` command is only available on Debian or Debian-based Linux distributions (such as Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Kali). It is not accessible on macOS. Alternatively, you can use package managers like [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), and [Nix](https://nixos.org/). You can find equivalent commands for each as follows

```
brew install package_name

sudo port install package_name

nix-env -i package_name
```

Before installing above package managers, you need to install XCode first.

Answer (score 2):

[Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) can also be used as package manager. It can be installed from [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/).

Alternatively, a free minimal installer is [Miniconda](https://conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).

Answer (score -4):

Alternatively You can use the brew or curl command for installing things, wherever **apt-get** is mentioned with a URL...

For example,

```
curl -O http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.8.1.0/magento-1.8.1.0.tar.gz
```