# How to install Vowpal Wabbit python interface

Tags: python, homebrew, vowpalwabbit

VW recently added a [python interface](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/tree/master/python), however I am having trouble finding instructions for how to install it. If I install VW from homebrew (brew install vowpal-wabbit) and I open python, and call

`import pyvw`

I get an ImportError.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to successfully install the Python interface to VW using the following steps. Note that this is on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine with Anaconda Python 2.7.10.

1. Prerequisites: Boost & miscellaneous Python development libraries:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev   
   sudo apt-get install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
   ```
2. `git clone` the [Vowpal Wabbit repo](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit) & enter the `python` directory.
3. `make` Vowpal Wabbit & test your installation using `python test.py`.

`import pyvw` should work from within a Python console as well.

Comment: Do we put the git clone of vowpal-wabbt into the anaconda directory?

Comment: @josh No need. You can place the directory anywhere.

Comment: I am confused. If you enter the python directory (I assume 'cd anaconda/bin') then how do you 'make' Vowpal Wabbit? Thank you.

Comment: @josh There is a `python` directory within the VW repo: https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/tree/master/python.

Comment: Sorry, I took it to mean the directory for python, as where it is installed. Silly me!

Comment: `apt-get` doesn't work on a Mac - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688424/why-is-apt-get-function-not-working-in-terminal-on-mac-osx-10-9 - you have to use `brew` so this will not work on a Mac as is.

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install vowpalwabbit
```

should give you the latest version. then do

```
from vowpalwabbit import sklearn_vw
```

This will give you scikit's vowpalwabbit