# How To Install PHP GMP on Mac OSX

Tags: php, macos, gmp

I am trying to install php5-gmp methods on my mac using command `"sudo apt-get install php5-gmp"`, but I get the error .

> "sudo: apt-get: command not found"

Comment: Because `apt-get` is a linux command which doe not exist on Mac OSX. You should use alternatives like `Hoebrew` and the like. for more into: [Why is not apt-get working on Mac OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688424/why-is-apt-get-function-not-working-in-terminal-on-mac-osx-10-9)

Comment: he meant to type 'homebrew' but I can't edit comments yet

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function gmp_init() still getting error