# Set environment variables on Mac OS X Sierra?

Tags: environment-variables, macos-sierra

For example, I want to follow this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688424/why-is-apt-get-function-not-working-in-terminal-on-mac-osx-10-9) on how to disable Brew analytics (under warning) but I have no idea how to find my environmental variables.

Most of the guides out there I found, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion), are all outdated; `~/.bash_profile` doesn't exist according to how the answer described it. Can some please explain to a new MacOS user how all this now works?

Please note my understanding of Unix-based filesystems are limited. Treat me as a noob.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create `~/.bash_profile`.  The easiest way to create it is to use the touch utility:  `touch .bash_profile` . It is common to have a `.profile` which is read if bash can not find .bash_profile.  You can get the documentation from a terminal with `man bash`.  You can edit either of these files with any text type editor (not word processor).

Comment: From the terminal, type `open .bash_profile` .  This will typically open the file with textedit.

Comment: Under OS X, the .bash_profile is executed each time you open a terminal session, ie Terminal application, \Shell, \New Window.  So in that sense it is permanent.  I'm not aware of Apple deleting the file on an OS update.

Comment: Didn't work for me. It also doesn't look like a solution, but a workaround. You are exporting the environment variables every time that a terminal is opened just for that terminal. But if you have an application that depends on this variable it will not work.

Comment: For the environment variables to take effect , you need to execute the file that you just modified. I use . .profile.  The first period tells the system to execute your file, so don't overlook it. If you have a terminal window open already, you need to execute the same command in that terminal window.

Comment: After adding `export PATH=<absolute/path/to/directory>:$PATH` to profile, you should run command `source ~/.bash_profile` to initialize the variable you just added, or open a new terminal instead.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using zsh like me, you need to modify `~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

I Android Gradle project root I do

```
gradle app:assembleDebug --stacktrace
```

but I get error

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 5.1.

and message says

> /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

but it is

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

so why is Gradle not building?