# Error when trying to do (sudo apt install flex bison): The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt

Tags: c, macos

I was trying to install flex bison so i used the command

```
sudo apt install flex bison
```

in my mac but it appears the error

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt. 
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

the i insert the command

```
java -version
```

to make sure i have java installed and it appears

```
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

so i don´t know what else i can do to try to install flex bison

Comment: Mac OS X doesn't have apt-get. Please check below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688424/why-is-the-apt-get-function-not-working-in-the-terminal-on-mac-os-x-v10-9-maver#:~:text=Mac%20OS%20X%20doesn't,Homebrew%20that%20is%20used%20instead.&text=Use%20Homebrew%20to%20install%20packages,otherwise%20use%20apt%2Dget%20for.

Comment: Why is this tagged as a C Question? It even says java in the question's Body.

Comment: @Cediwelli Likely because OP is trying to write some parser in C. Java shows up because macOS simply don't support apt-get

Comment: The error message is probably related to this "apt": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/GettingStarted.html#what-is-apt - which is of course not Debian's apt-get

Comment: Thanks to @all for the help sry i was used to work with linux didn't know that