# Command-line SVN client for Mac

Tags: macos, svn

I purchased a new Mac running [Mac OS X v10.8.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion). I've seen it written in [various](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#osx) [places](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) that SVN is installed on OS X by default, but when I open a terminal and type `which svn` the program is not found. I've also run `find / -name svn` to check if it's installed somewhere that hasn't been added the the `PATH` variable.

So it seems like `svn` is not installed. Where can I get an OS X version of the official command-line SVN client?

Answer (score 46):

The default SVN version which is installed along with Xcode command line tools is 1.7.x. If you're fine with this version, than that should be enough. I want to select my SVN version and for that I'm using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29).

Install Homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Install SVN:

```
brew install svn
```

To install a specific SVN version, check available versions:

```
brew versions svn
```

This command will list all available SVN versions.

Here's how you can install other than the default version (based on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/gcatlin/1847248))

```
# Update brew
brew update

# Switch to brew base directory
cd $( brew --prefix )

# Check old versions
brew versions svn

# Here's sample output
1.8.9    git checkout 9b75c92 /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.8.8    git checkout c6cf8ac /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.8.5    git checkout fa4311c /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.8.4    git checkout ce669eb /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.8.3    git checkout 9b438ce /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.8.0    git checkout f56b641 /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.8.1    git checkout 55577bb /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.7.10   git checkout 0060dc3 /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.7.9    git checkout b0e6223 /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.7.8    git checkout f7a42d2 /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.7.7    git checkout a6dcc41 /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.7.6    git checkout 6b8d25f /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.7.5    git checkout 5d5cd70 /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.7.4    git checkout dc4245c /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.7.3    git checkout eb97154 /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.7.2    git checkout d89bf83 /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.6.17   git checkout 6e2d550 /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
1.6.16   git checkout 83ed494 /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb

# Install SVN version 1.6.17. You can just copy line from output
git checkout 6e2d550 /usr/local/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
brew install subversion

# Switch to SVN version 1.6
brew switch subversion 1.6.17
```

Now that the older SVN version is installed, we can re-install the latest formula in order to keep our repository clean:

```
git checkout -- Library/Formula/subversion.rb
```

Now you can switch between versions using `svn switch` command.

Make sure that brew's executables are first in your environment path. Check in your .bash_profile that path is set as follows:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
```

Comment: I was able to install a version of svn using `brew install svn`

Answer (score 12):

For me, it just worked with brew on MacOS version 10.15.4

```
COMMAND:- brew install svn
```

That is all, you will have an svn command-line client installed.

Happy Coding!

Comment: This helped me, however I got an error as "xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun", so executed following to install xcode and got svn working.
xcode-select --install

I do not know if installing xcode only would have resolved the issue.

my mac version - 10.15.6

thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you have **HomeBrew** installed,
try this command: `brew install subversion`

after that, `brew link subversion`

Hopefully, you will be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Subversion itself is no longer included with OS X. It's now included as part of Xcode. So one option is to install Xcode and then [install the Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools). If you're not going to install Xcode anyway then you may be better off downloading a different installation of Subversion. On top of that the Xcode version is usually fairly behind on releases now.

So I'd suggest getting it from one of the sources on the [Subversion Projects Binaries Page](https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#osx).

Answer (score 1):

You can get SVN with Xcode, [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29), [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts), and probably other sources as well. The latter two options will probably stay more up to date than Xcode's installation.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode's command line tools can be downloaded from here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#

April 2014 version direct download link:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/command_line_tools_os_x_mavericks_for_xcode__april_2014/command_line_tools_for_osx_mavericks_april_2014.dmg

Answer (score 0):

**For newer users or Mojave OS users**: 
I am using my MAC running Mojave OS. It seems that Apple fixed Mojave and updated OS so that SVN is added back again (it was not by default when Mojave was out). To check if you have SVN installed simple run terminal (command+space than type 'terminal' and press enter). 
In terminal type :
 `svn --version` 
or: 
`svn help`

If you don't see "unknown command",  you have SVN installed already. Otherwise try updating Mojave OS in case you avoid auto updates.