# Xcode is not showing changes for files on SVN

Tags: xcode, svn

We're using svn for version control on our Mac. Its working cool. But the only problem is we're multiple devs developing together and everyone can see any file changes status inside their Xcode ( [attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2036/1603234) next to the file ) in their Xcode except me. How to resolve this?

This is what I want (see "M" next to the file name),

[image]

Even Xcode Source Control Menu is showing no changes.

[image]

I'm not sure if there's anything to set here?

[image]

I have checkout the code again and again, but still the problem persist.

I'm not sure, why this "Working Copies" menu "iOS" is disabled? Its enabled on other machine.

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this problem, the following is my solution, hope I can help you.

1. Start the terminal, enter the code in the folder.
2. Type the command - **svn status**.

---

### The output will be similar to this

- svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
- svn: E155036: The working copy at '/Users/chao/svn/project'
  is too old (format 29) to work with client version '1.9.4 (r1740329)' (expects 
  format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.

---

3. Type the command - **svn upgrade**.
4. The problem is resolved,I wish you good luck.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Is there another solution？

Answer (score 0):

SVN can define status of working copy files and directories comparing your local files with the current repository located on the remote SVN server.

I believe that checking "Refresh server status automatically" will do the job.

You can say this is true when your local files will have attributes aside (U, M etc)

Having no luck, you may run the command line tool, which is usually more verbose. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19922150/195812

Comment: So @Hemang , please replace the snapshot above,  exposing your actual setting.

Comment: Its the same as before. No changes.

Comment: Ok. Can you show us the best diagnostic message you have?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't  stick with a software I can't get proper diagnostics from ... As said in the answer itself,  try a command line tool (for debugging  this issue at least)