# I need to install Tortoise SVN on mac but its not available. Can someone recommend any other version control software that's close to Tortoise?

Tags: macos, svn, tortoisesvn

My team uses Tortoise SVN on Windows, since I'm using Mac, I need version control software for mac so that it doesn't conflict with Tortoise SVN. In other words, my teammates would be checking the code through Tortoise SVN and I'll be checking in the code using some other software. Is it possible? Which version control software can I use? Can I use Git and other team mates can use Tortoise for same codebase?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to install svn without Tortoise. Tortoise is only a graphical interface for svn. Probably this may help:

[Command-line SVN client for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921714/command-line-svn-client-for-mac)

You may simply install it with brew.

Otherwise install it with a graphical Interface:

The options you find here:

https://alternativeto.net/software/tortoisesvn/?platform=mac

Comment: Hi @popeinvestor - thanks much for the response. I'll give it a try. Does that mean I can use the SmartSVN client and other teammates can continue using Tortoise SVN without any conflict?

Comment: Yes that's it. The compatibility is only by the svn protocol and not by the client. Its only a GUI for the svn. But you may also use svn with a command line. By the way please vote the answer for me...