# "g++" not found in PATH [mac/Eclipse/XCODE installed/CDT downloaded]

Tags: c++, xcode, eclipse, macos, gcc

I get this error when I try to build a c++ project, however I can run cpp apps in Xcode, I've downloaded CDT for Eclipse, so the compiler must be installed.

echo $PATH:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

I'm using Mac, I've found posts saying download gcc or Xcode, or solutions for Windows, it's very frustrating that I can't find the answer for such an easy problem, so please… How can I set the PATH variable for my cpp projects in Eclipse?

Comment: On OS X, llvm/clang is used as compiler, so the command is `clang++`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools) should help. It looks like you need to install XCode command line tools separately to use compilers and build systems outside of XCode (e.g. on the command line or in Eclipse).