# Install Xcode clang++ to /usr/bin in OSX 10.8.5

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11, command-line

My /usr/bin/ directory contains an older version of clang++:

```
$ which clang++
/usr/bin/clang++
$ clang++ --version
Apple clang version 2.1 (tags/Apple/clang-163.7.1) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

However, the version of clang++ used by Xcode is newer:

```
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

How do I install the clang++ compiler used by Xcode into /usr/bin/? Also, all newer libraries (e.g., C++11) should be installed into their appropriate directories. I'm trying to develop software using the command-line tools (not the Xcode IDE).

Answer (score 0):

**Executive Summary:** 

The most recent Command Line Tools has to be installed.  In order to obtain the installation file for 10.8.5, download it from the [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com).

**Details:**

I am currently running OS X Mavericks on my MacBook Pro.  However, when creating platform independent C++ code and the respective tests in CppUnit, I followed directions for using NetBeans 7.4 and the respective OS X Command Line Tools installation from the [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).  When at the Apple Developer site, search using *command line tools* to obtain the most recent installation file for Mountain Lion.

Here is a more direct [dedicated Xcode link](https://developer.apple.com/xcode).  Then click the *View Downloads* link when there.  Remember an Apple Developer account is necessary (it is free).

Both of these links are from the more detailed Stack Overflow post [Xcode 4.4 and later install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools), where the comments address older versions of OS X.

Note that the Apple wording of *Requires Mac OS X 10.7.3 or later* means that version and the more recent ones (e.g. 10.7.4, 10.8.5, 10.9.2, etc.).