# Mongodb installation on Mac

Tags: macos, mongodb

When i try to install mangodb in Mac os, it shows error like this

```
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//ccHtrnbk.out
make: *** [php_mongo.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

I'm following this tutorial
http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-php-mongodb-mongo-driver-on-linux-mac-os-x-windows-unix-bsd/

and in installation command `sudo pecl install mongo` it asking this request

```
Build with Cyrus SASL (MongoDB Enterprise Authentication) support? [no] :
```

How can solve this?
Thanks

Comment: I think this is a XCode issue... Did you update the compiler recently? Can you install any PECL extension at all?

Comment: Which OSX & XCode versions are you running anyway?

Comment: @bjori - How can update the compiler? I installed PECL in local.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools