# overriding the definiton of "complex"

Tags: c, xcode

I have a homework assignment to write a class that defines a type with "`typedef`"

according to the assignment, the type's name *must* be "complex" with lowercase c, and it must sit in complex.h file

however, i am developing this assignment in `xcode`, and this type is already defined there by objective c.

how can i make `xcode` favor my type and my file, over the default one, without renaming any of the files and object types ?

complex.h

```
#ifndef complex_complex_h
#define complex_complex_h



typedef struct complex complex;

struct complex{

    double real;
    double imaginary;

};


 complex A;
 complex B;
 complex C;
 complex D;
 complex E;
 complex F;


void read_comp (char * complexName, double real, double imaginary);
void print_comp (char * complexName);
#endif
```

complex.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include  "complex.h"

  complex get_complex_from_name(char * complexName);
  complex notFound;

 complex get_complex_from_name(char * complexName){
    if(strcmp(complexName,"A")==0 ){
        return A;
    }
    if(strcmp(complexName, "B")==0){
        return B;
    }

    if(strcmp(complexName, "C")==0){
        return C;
    }
    if(strcmp(complexName, "D")==0){
        return D;
    }
    if(strcmp(complexName, "E")==0){
        return E;
    }
    if(strcmp(complexName, "F")==0){
        return F;
    }
    return notFound;
}

void read_comp(char *complexName, double real, double imaginary){
    struct complex comp = get_complex_from_name(complexName);
    comp.real = real;
    comp.imaginary = imaginary;
}

void print_comp(char *complexName){
    struct complex comp = get_complex_from_name(complexName);
    printf("%s=%f+(%f)i",complexName,comp.real, comp.imaginary);
}
```

compiler throws errors, doesnt know which complex i mean

Comment: Your question is tagged C, so what does it matter what Objective C does? Put your code in a `.c` file and Xcode will treat it as C.

Comment: because i am trying to define a class that is already define somewhere, it uses the "somewhere" define class, instead of mine

Comment: get the command line tools and compile it with `clang`?

Comment: @japreiss your answer helped, if you put it in an answer, i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get the XCode Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools) and compile your code as straight C on the command line using `clang`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `#undef complex` to undefine the Objective C implementation of complex and then `#define` your own.