# C libraries installation on Mac OSX

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I have recently switched from Windows to Mac . I was told that Xcode has the C/C++ libraries(GCC) included. Apparently, the new Xcode 5 doesn't have them. As IDE, I have CodeBlocks downloaded. How do I install the libraries for CodeBlocks in Mac?

Comment: You might consider asking on http://apple.stackexchange.com/.  Independently of that, you should find the related questions about installing the command line tools from XCode.  That changed recently, so I've forgotten the answer, but I know it's around here somewhere. For example, a search on SO with 'xcode command line' reveals [XCode 4.4 and later install command line tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools)

Comment: Btw: Xcode5 can hardly be described as new anymore - Xcode6 is now available.

Comment: You can install the libraries from Xcode, under the option "install command line tools". If you specifically want gcc instead of clang, you can install it using macports or homebrew.

Comment: @marko calling developer preview software `available` isn't completely accurate.

Comment: where are you getting hung up, what do you mean "libraries for CodeBlocks in Mac"? it is in the compilation phase, you can't link to the libraries, or your compiler can't find the headers? or you can't build CodeBlocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple deprecated `gcc` in XCode5 (after giving warning for quite a few releases).   The main reason for this was that `clang` is now the system compiler, along with libc++, its accompanying standard library.  One of the motivations for the move to clang is that the IDE makes heavy use of the compiler's modular architecture for code syntax highlighting, indexing and refactoring.

I can't imagine many reasons why you actually would specifically need GCC if building software on MacOSX and iOS. Clang has had the edge of GCC in both compilation speed and standards compliance for some time.

What you may need to do, if you haven't already, is install the optional XCode5 command-line tools package (the UI for this changed a few versions ago - google for the solution to your version of XCode5). This installs `clang` and other command-line tools (or more likely symlinks to them) in `/usr`, which where external tools and build and configuration tools such as `cmake` and `autoconf` expect them to be.    `clang` is also aliased to `cc`.

Comment: Yes, Clang is better but I just prefer GCC for no reason. Anyways I found this GCC auto installer on Github that helped me. Thanks for the info.