# how to use and install SystemC in terminal mac OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, installation, systemc

how to use and install **SystemC** in terminal mac OS X?
I tried the Logic poet application, But i use os x 10.10 so it doesn't work.
so i want to know how can i compile and execute SystemC in terminal.
I could't find the detail of SystemC in terminal.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is correct and perfectly fine, however, I thought I'd also answer and provide a little more detail.

**Install Apple's "Command Line Tools"**

You have two options: install Xcode (a big download), or just the command line tools (a much smaller download). If your goal is simply building SystemC applications at the command line, then I recommend the latter.

Install Apple's "Command Line Tools" by launching Terminal, entering

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

then clicking Install. After that, you'll have `make`, `clang` and more available at the command line.

**Build and install Accellera's SystemC implementation**

Download the latest release from the [Accellera Downloads page](http://www.accellera.org/downloads/standards/systemc) (annoyingly, you'll have to provide a few personal details) and extract the contents of the .zip file.

I like to keep a copy of the SystemC source code available, because it can be useful for debugging or understanding how something works. Therefore, I move the extracted folder (`systemc-2.3.1`) into `~/Work/Other`. That's where I keep source code for third party libraries. However, you can put it wherever you like.

Open Terminal, change into the extracted folder (`systemc-2.3.1`), and execute:

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ export CXX=clang++
$ ../configure --with-arch-suffix=
$ make install
```

The `--with-arch-suffix=` option prevents a `-macosx64` suffix being add to the `lib` folder name, allowing your build scripts to be simpler.

After that process, the salient `include` and `lib` folders should be available within the `systemc-2.3.1` folder.

**Configure your build environment**

There are many ways you can do this; I have a simple approach that I believe is close to what the SystemC maintainers envisioned. I define two environment variables in my `.bash_profile` (which is executed for every new Terminal session on OS X):

```
export CXX="clang++ -fcolor-diagnostics"
export SYSTEMC_HOME=~/Work/Other/systemc-2.3.1
```

**Build a SystemC application**

You could use Make, the quintessential build tool, which you get with Apple's "Command Line Tools", or any one of the plethora of other options. I use [SCons](http://www.scons.org/) with `SConstruct` files that look something like this:

```py
import os
env = Environment(CXX=os.environ["CXX"],
                  SYSTEMC_HOME=os.environ["SYSTEMC_HOME"],
                  CPPPATH="$SYSTEMC_HOME/include",
                  LIBPATH="$SYSTEMC_HOME/lib")
env.Program("main.cpp", LIBS="systemc")
```

**View trace (VCD) files**

[Scansion](http://www.logicpoet.com/scansion/) is a nice tool for this. [GTKWave](http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net) is another option, but it's a bit clunky.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you have [xcode command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-install-command-line-tools) installed.

Follow instructions provided in the [official repository](https://github.com/systemc/systemc-2.3/blob/master/INSTALL).

---

From personal experience.

Compiling SystemC library with `clang` results in `segmentation fault: 11`
error every time I include `systemc` library into my code. To avoid this use `gcc` instead.

> Note that I use gcc-8, installed with [homebrew](https://brew.sh).

```
$ cd path/to/systemc-2.3.3
$ mkdir objdir
$ cd objdir
$ export CXX=g++-8
$ ../configure
$ make
$ make install
```

Use `$ make check` to launch examples compilation and unit tests.

To compile and run [hello world example](http://www.asic-world.com/code/systemc/hello.cpp):

```
$ export SYSTEMC_HOME=path/to/systemc-2.3.3
$ g++-8 hello.cpp -o hello.o -L $SYSTEMC_HOME/lib-macosx64 -I $SYSTEMC_HOME/include/ -l systemc
$ ./hello.o
```

> Tested on macOS 10.13.6; gcc version 8.2.0; systemc-2.3.3

Comment: The GitHub link above is **not** an official repository.  The instructions can be found in the `INSTALL` file of the extracted SystemC source package.

Answer (score 0):

## Install

Go here click the first link and fill in your information to get the source code

http://www.accellera.org/downloads/standards/systemc

Then `cd` to the folder

Then run the following commands

```
./configure --with-unix-layout
gmake
sudo gmake install
gmake clean
```

After you do that it should all be saved in your use/local/(lib&include) directories

## To Use

In code do this
    #include "systemc.h"

I use a single makefile normally. But you could write the following to link the library. Given your cpp file is called main.

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lsystemc
```