# SystemC IDE out of the box without compiling lib for windows and mac?

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, systemc

Is there an IDE with SystemC out of the box without compiling the lib for windows AND mac?
Looking for a download, but can't find. Why everybody needs to compile it on its own?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any C++ IDE will work once you have the library installed. I recommend Eclipse for C++ that runs on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

EDA tool vendors like Cadence and Synopsys will provide you a pre-compiled library and IDE, but not for free.

Also see:

http://karibe.co.ke/2014/02/setting-up-systemc-and-eclipse-for-c-hardware-simulation/

[how to use and install SystemC in terminal mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961573/how-to-use-and-install-systemc-in-terminal-mac-os-x)