# SystemC on Mac error with Makefile

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, clang++, systemc

I need to start working on a project with SystemC. I managed to compile SystemC according to this instructions: [how to use and install SystemC in terminal mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961573/how-to-use-and-install-systemc-in-terminal-mac-os-x)

Afterwards I adjusted the `SYSTEMC_HOME` variable in Makefile.config to `"SYSTEMC_HOME?=~/Work/Other/systemc-2.3.1"`
The problem occurs when i try to compile and run any of the provided examples.
The error I get is:

```
ld: unknown option: -rpath=/Users/admin/Work/Other/systemc-2.3.1/lib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 
(use -void to see invocation)
```

The command I run is:

```
make -f Makefile run
```

And the whole output from the console:

```
simple_fifo admin$ make -f Makefile run
clang++ -fcolor-diagnostics  -g -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Werror -L. -L.. -L /Users/admin/Work/Other/systemc-2.3.1/lib -Wl,-rpath=/Users/admin/Work/Other/systemc-2.3.1/lib -o simple_fifo.x simple_fifo.o -lsystemc -lm  2>&1 | c++filt
ld: unknown option: -rpath=/Users/admin/Work/Other/systemc-2.3.1/lib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -void to see invocation)
make: *** [simple_fifo.x] Error 1
```

Any hints on what to look for would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is a GNU linker feature, not Clang.

Edit `examples/sysc/Makefile.rules` and replace:

`LDFLAG_RPATH     ?= -Wl,-rpath=`

with

`LDFLAG_RPATH     ?= -Wl,-rpath,`