# How to install SystemC on xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, systemc

Is it possible to install SystemC on XCode? If so, how would I do it? Do I just need to set up some libraries and point xCode at them? I've set up openGL on xcode before but, I can't similar looking libraries for SystemC.

I tried following the top voted instructions in the link suggested and got these errors on the `make install` command:

```
...
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
../../libtool: line 1096: cd: .libs/libsystemc.lax/libkernel.a: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [libsystemc.la] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I got the same error trying the other instructions.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961573/how-to-use-and-install-systemc-in-terminal-mac-os-x

Comment: @rmaddy that is for terminal/system not xcode specifically.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use SystemC with xCode, you have to build the library first. You can follow instructions @rmaddy suggested : [how to use and install SystemC in terminal mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961573/how-to-use-and-install-systemc-in-terminal-mac-os-x)
I suppose you installed SystemC (result of `make install`) in **/usr/local/systemc** and so you have **/usr/local/systemc/include** containing SystemC headers and **/usr/local/systemc/lib-macosx64** containing the library.

Create a new xCode project. **File** -> **New** -> **Project**. Choose OS X / Application and finally **Command Line Tool** for example. Add a product name (SystemCExample) and choose **C++** language.

Select your target (SystemCExample) on the left panel and then be sure you selected your target in the top left list (and not the project). Select the area **Build Settings** and under **Search Paths** you will find **Header Search Paths**. Click on the "+" and add SystemC headers path (**/usr/local/systemc/include**).

Then, select the section **Build Phases** and either add the path manually or drag and drop the static (`libsystemc.a`) or dynamic version (`libsystemc.dylib`) of SystemC library you can find in **/usr/local/systemc/lib-macosx64** in **Link Binary with Libraries** part.

Finally, just add a minimalist SystemC code and press the build and run button:

```
#include <systemc>

int sc_main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    sc_core::sc_start();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that makes sense though I'm having trouble getting past the first part as described in the edit.