# Beginniner- Connecting my Terminal to my Github "No Developer Tools were found...?"

Tags: ios, xcode, git, macos, github

Beginner here, trying to set up my terminal to communicate with my Github so that I can commit and pull a file that I need.

I downloaded git for Mac from the main site. I couldn't find walkthrough of git from the beginning that could help with this question.

So I type in git --version and I get an error saying "no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools."

I've probably done this 3 times. Installing the Xcode.

Once the install is complete, I repeat the git --version and still get the error.

Do I need Xcode to simply have my terminal communicate with my Github? How do I get it to work if I do? I've seen a few questions asked on here relating to this but I did not find them helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Did you launch Xcode once?

Comment: I've searched for Xcode and it doesn't show up on my Mac. Does that mean it wasn't installed correctly? I figured it was a plugin or something and wouldn't show up in a search?

Comment: Install it using AppStore and then check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools :)

Comment: It's an app.  You would download it from the Mac App Store, or the [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

Comment: Do I even need Xcode to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Some commands in the terminal require Xcode to be installed, so you'll need to download Xcode from the app store. Just to let you know, it is about a 2.6 GB download.

Comment: Ok thanks! I suspect my previous 3 download attempts failed for some reason. Finally had a successful download/install apparently as git --version worked this time.