# How to use ifort in mac osx

Tags: macos

I have a problem compiling a program with Intel fortran on my Mac. I have a makefile in a folder and when I use `make` command, I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o 
make: *** [../BIN/double_par_TMATRIX] Error 1
```

I found this link which mentions a possible solution, but I don't know how to apply it.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/library-not-found-for-lcrt1105o

According to this link, the solution is to Add GNU C/C++ compiler option `-mmacosx-version-min=10.4` to the compilation command line. But i don't know what this solution means exactly.

I have mac os x 10.9.5 and I have xcode 5.1.1 installed on it.
Do anyone knows how should I add this option?

Thanks

Comment: Can you put a copy of your *Makefile* in your question? Also, what version of the Intel Fortran compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the `-mmacosx-version-min=...` option to `flags`. I'm guessing you want to do `-mmacosx-version-min=10.9` because you're on OSX 10.9.5. So you should end up with:

```
ifeq ($(compilemode),release)
  flags   := $(flags_1) -parallel -openmp -O3 -xT -axT 
else
  flags   := $(flags_1)
endif
flags += -mmacosx-version-min=10.9
```

---

UPDATE: Try commenting out or removing your line calling `ld`. It doesn't look like it belongs there:

```
ld -mmacosx-version-min=10.6
```

Comment: I added your suggestion but unfortunately I still have this error 

ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o
make: *** [../BIN/double_par_TMATRIX] Error 1

Comment: @Amin Try following this: [Xcode 4.4 and later install Command Line Tools](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/369450).