# Xcode10 cannot run the iOS12 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode10, ios12

[image]

Running the iOS12 Simulator on xcode10 failed. but other versions of the Simulator were normal.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[image]
The problem is solved by moving the xcode file location under the application file, then restarting the xcode and running it.

Comment: More detailed information on where and from you moved exactly which file would make this answer better. Also, the screen shot as proof you ran the simulator adds very little.

Answer (score 0):

Its happens some time so, You have to do **"Erase Reset Content and Settings"** of simulator by below step.

```
 -> Click on simulator 
    -> Go on "Hardware" in menu bar
       -> Select "Erase Reset Content and Settings..."
```

Give some time after done it. Close Xcode and reopen it.

Comment: As you said, the result is still not good, the iOS12 version simulator does not work properly.The page always shows the chrysanthemum

Comment: There are other versions of xcode installed in my computer, is it related to this?

Comment: When you open any project .. do right click and choose xcode as you want btw have you tried with above suggestion ?

Comment: I only choose xcode10 to open my project, then turned on the iOS12 version of the simulator, tried your advice, and the simulator still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It may needs to set you command line tool.

Reset your simulator and install command line tool for Xcode 10.

**Reset Simulator:**

[image]

See Here: [Xcode - install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-install-command-line-tools/45566089#45566089)

Comment: According to your method, there is no solution to my problem, but I have found the solution to the problem. I will write it in the answer later. Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This symptom usually appears in two cases:

1. when the system app (eg: SpringBoard) crashes while setting up the debugging session.
2. because of buggy 3rd party kexts interfering with the normal operation of the system.

If you are seeing any background crashes of the system app around the time of the failure, that's the likely cause.  Otherwise, you should check the output of `kextstat | grep -v com.apple`, remove any listed 3rd party kexts, reboot, and try again.