# Deleted Developer folder by accident in iOS 11 help me

Tags: ios, directory, delete-directory

I am facing a problem. I deleted the Developer folder in the directory .
I've tried to use xcode to reinstall this folder but it keeps giving me a error

I've also tried to make the directory using sudo/root but all I get is 
the error below I can create any other folder name anything else just not Developer

```
jamnies:/ root# sudo mkdir Developer
mkdir: cannot create directory 'Developer': Operation not permitted
jamnies:/ root# sudo mkdir Develope
jamnies:/ root#
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to simply reinstall Xcode (though it takes a bit of time).

If you don't want to do that you could try manually reinstalling the CommandLineTools and the CoreSimulator.framework (these are the only two things that my Developer directory contains)
To do this you can find more info here:

[Xcode - install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-install-command-line-tools)

[How to recover from deleting Xcode CoreSimulator devices from disk?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231105/how-to-recover-from-deleting-xcode-coresimulator-devices-from-disk)

But if I were you I would just simply reinstall Xcode.