# Unable to install python-geohash using PIP in mac terminal

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, geohashing

Installing python-geocode has not been easy.  I'm running Anaconda on my mac (10.14.4), and in terminal, I'm using:

```
pip install python-geohash
```

I get the following error:

```
    warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
  1 warning generated.
  g++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/anaconda3/lib -arch x86_64 -L/anaconda3/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/src/geohash.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/_geohash.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
  ld: library not found for -lstdc++
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for python-geohash
  Running setup.py clean for python-geohash
Failed to build python-geohash
```

This makes me think some libraries that I need to run python-geohash are either out of date or not installed yet.  Can anyone tell me specifically what the issue is here?

Comment: Do you have [Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-install-command-line-tools) installed?

Comment: I'm not sure - how can I check?

Comment: appears so, when I use: xcode-select --install , i get: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: I'm in the process of installing Xcode_10.2 .  I have no idea if this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a very old question. However, in case someone face a similar issue (I just did), I found a solution here:

https://aichamp.wordpress.com/2019/11/06/error-with-python-geohash-installation-while-installing-superset-in-osx-catalina/

so basically run the following command (for macOS):

```
sudo CFLAGS=-stdlib=libc++ pip3 install python-geohash
```