# How do I stop command line developers tool icon from showing

Tags: eclipse, macos, intellij-idea, command-line-tool

This isn’t much of a big problem just a nuisance.

So when ever I open and or close eclipse/IntelliJ application on my Mac, this icon shows up saying “the git command requires the command line developers tool. Would you like to install?”.

[image]

This icon shows up when ever I do anything relating to java programming (opening/ closing IDE, creating a new class, sometimes when configuring main class, opening a new project). I always press “cancel” instead of “install” when the icon appears.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The "git" command requires the command line developer tools. Would you like to install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59080773/the-git-command-requires-the-command-line-developer-tools-would-you-like-to-i)

Comment: See also this thread https://superuser.com/questions/322633/how-to-install-git-on-mac-without-xcode

Comment: This is actually a feature when developing on a Mac using git or other command line tools, as the XCode command line tools are kept up to date by Apple.  If you don't use git, then it just gets in your way, but it has advantages you might want to look into as git is a very frequently used tool when being more than one developer on a project.

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrade** your **Eclipse** to 2020-09 (4.17) or at least EGit to 5.9.

Eclipse does not require to have the command line Git to be installed, but calls the `git` command to check whether the command line Git is installed (and if it's installed, how it is configured). A change that came with a macOS update redirects the `git` command causing this dialog to pop up. For details see [Eclipse bug 564372](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564372).

For IntelliJ see [JetBrains' bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com), e.g. [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-25196).