# Unable to install command line developer tools for "git"

Tags: macos, github

[image]

[image]

While trying to open up Atom while just starting to learn PHP, I ran into this notification as soon as I opened up the app. I'm completely new to this, so I'm not very sure how this works or what I need to do. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 5):

This answer solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73725957/5396995

-> Run `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch` on terminal

Comment: This one solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 1):

This is a current problem with the CommandLineTool. I found a solution at this [post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/you-cant-install-the-software-because-its-not-available-on-the-software-update-server/82346/2). So you can manually remove the CommandLineTool with the following command:

```sh
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

At the end you can manually add an older version of the CommandLineTool. Therefore you need to download the version from the [apple download page](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/). Otherwise if you get a message that the CommandLineTool can be updated, I would recommend to do this.