# Unable to install Cocoapods on macOS 10.15.4

Tags: ios, swift, ruby, macos

When I perform `sudo gem install cocoapods` it returns the following:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200524-27428-t6f6h6.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.12.2/gem_make.out
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Do not ever do this! The Ruby that ships as part of macOS is *only for internal use by Apple itself*. If you want to use Ruby, *you must install an appropriate Ruby implementation yourself*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First install Homebrew if you don't have it: https://brew.sh/index_pt-br

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Second, install ruby if you don't have it:
https://www.ruby-lang.org/pt/documentation/installation/

```
brew install ruby
```

You can also follow these steps: https://gist.github.com/monicao/d372716cdfbb7e9cf692

Then, close your terminal and reopen it again.

Always use sudo to install cocoapods:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Also, you need to install Xcode's developer tools. The easiest way to do this is through terminal ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools/9329325#9329325))

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Installing Homebrew allowed me to proceed with installation - thankyou!