# TypeError: Class advice impossible in Python3. Use the @implementer class decorator instead

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to install Hugging Face's Transformers using,

> pip install transformers

but it's giving me that error.
I tried installing the NVIDIA's Apex but it doesn't work on Mac.

P.S: I want to install transformers on mac (no gpu support)

```
!pip install transformers
```

I also installed NVIDIA's apex.

ERROR

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-279c49635b32> in <module>
----> 1 import transformers

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/__init__.py in <module>
     21 
     22 # Configurations
---> 23 from .configuration_albert import ALBERT_PRETRAINED_CONFIG_ARCHIVE_MAP, AlbertConfig
     24 from .configuration_auto import ALL_PRETRAINED_CONFIG_ARCHIVE_MAP, CONFIG_MAPPING, AutoConfig
     25 from .configuration_bart import BartConfig

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/configuration_albert.py in <module>
     16 """ ALBERT model configuration """
     17 
---> 18 from .configuration_utils import PretrainedConfig
     19 
     20 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py in <module>
     23 from typing import Dict, Tuple
     24 
---> 25 from .file_utils import CONFIG_NAME, cached_path, hf_bucket_url, is_remote_url
     26 
     27 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py in <module>
    101 
    102 try:
--> 103     from apex import amp  # noqa: F401
    104 
    105     _has_apex = True

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apex/__init__.py in <module>
     16 from apex.exceptions import (ApexAuthSecret,
     17                              ApexSessionSecret)
---> 18 from apex.interfaces import (ApexImplementation,
     19                              IApex)
     20 from apex.lib.libapex import (groupfinder,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apex/interfaces.py in <module>
      8     pass
      9 
---> 10 class ApexImplementation(object):
     11     """ Class so that we can tell if Apex is installed from other 
     12     applications

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apex/interfaces.py in ApexImplementation()
     12     applications
     13     """
---> 14     implements(IApex)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zope/interface/declarations.py in implements(*interfaces)
    704     # the coverage for this block there. :(
    705     if PYTHON3:
--> 706         raise TypeError(_ADVICE_ERROR % 'implementer')
    707     _implements("implements", interfaces, classImplements)
    708 

TypeError: Class advice impossible in Python3.  Use the @implementer class decorator instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have installed the [wrong `apex` project](https://pypi.org/project/apex/); that's a project for the Pyramid web framework and the most recent release on PyPI is not compatible with Python 3.

You need to *uninstall* that project, then install the correct project, the [NVIDIA Apex project](https://nvidia.github.io/apex/). Be careful, that project has [different installation instructions](https://github.com/nvidia/apex#quick-start), which involve creating a local clone of the git repository then compiling the extension code. Take into account that this requires a C++ compiler and a recent CUDA release. If you have the [XCode command-line tools installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/how-to-install-xcode-command-line-tools) then you have the required compiler, and NVIDIA provides [installation instructions for CUDA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html).

To uninstall the wrong project, it should be sufficient to use (from your notebook):

```sh
pip uninstall apex
```

then follow the prompts. You'll have to *restart your notebook* if you haven't already done so. You can verify that the project is gone by using `import apex` in a *fresh* Python interpreter or restarted notebook. If `import apex` still succeeds, use `print(apex.__file__)` to locate where it is installed so you can manually delete the `apex` directory and any `apex-*.dist-info` directories in the same location.

I do note that the project appears to only support Linux and to a lesser extent, Windows, and that there is an [open bug report on using it on macOS Mojave](https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex/issues/155). I don't have a CUDA-capable Mac myself (MacBook Pros don't have a NVIDIA GPU), so I can't verify if this is still an issue, although I suspect that that bug report is no longer applicable (the specific component in question has [since been moved to the `contrib` area](https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex/blob/4ef930c1c884fdca5f472ab2ce7cb9b505d26c1a/apex/contrib/optimizers/fp16_optimizer.py) and has had numerous updates; there have been [over 500 commits to the project](https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex/compare/d137b800f739b66e253636404885f2c4f0b9254b...4ef930c1c884fdca5f472ab2ce7cb9b505d26c1a) since that bug report).