# How to install `gcc` to get C++17 support on osx?

Tags: c++

I am not a C++ developer, but I am trying to get a C++ compiler for running my Lua-lsp and linters. I tried to install `gcc` with homebrew, but still the version I checked is always `4.2.1`.

I am installing like this:

```
brew install gcc@7
```

When I do version check, I get this

```
gcc -dumpversion
// 4.2.1
```

Is the version wrong or is the way I install is incorrect?

Comment: macOS (formerly OS X) has XCode + clang both of which support C++20, C++17 etc. Why GCC? If you install XCode + [XCode Command-Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/how-to-install-xcode-command-line-tools) you get everything you need. You can even install the tools independently if you want.

Comment: [The binary should be called gcc-7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297052)