# Does FreePascal support Macbook Pro m2?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I use Macbook Pro on m2. I want to download FreePascal's ide. But I didn't found on the website.  Can you guys help me?

I'm expecting link description for FreePascal.

Thanks.

Comment: FreePascal supports LLVM, apparently: https://wiki.freepascal.org/LLVM

Comment: _“ I'm expecting link description for FreePascal.”_ - mmmmhmmm

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to install the Lazarus system, which is available for the M1/M2. The instructions are the same as for an Intel system, so basically you'll want to:

1. Install [Xcode](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12).
2. Install [Xcode command line tools](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode); see also [How to install Xcode Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9329243/4299358)) or [Embarcadero's help](https://www.embarcadero.com/starthere/berlin/mobdevsetup/ios/en/installing_the_xcode_command_line_tools_on_a_mac.html).
3. Install [FPC (Free Pascal Compiler) 3.3.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20macOS%20x86-64/Lazarus%202.2.4/fpc-3.2.2.intelarm64-macosx.dmg/download) or newer. If you're running Homebrew, you could instead install FPC as easily as running this command in the Terminal:

   ```
   brew install fpc
   ```
4. Install [Lazarus 2.2.4](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20macOS%20x86-64/Lazarus%202.2.4/Lazarus-2.2.4-0-x86_64-macosx.pkg/download) or newer. Again, if you're running Homebrew, this could also be done by running the following command:

   ```
   brew install --cask lazarus
   ```

You can find more details about macOS installations of Lazarus/FPC in general [at FreePascal](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Installing_Lazarus_on_macOS).

And in particular [support regarding Apple Silicon (M1/M2)](https://wiki.freepascal.org/macOS_Big_Sur_changes_for_developers#ARM64.2FAArch64.2FAppleSilicon_Support):

- Note that the current FPC version 3.2.2 is already compiled for M1/M2. You're downloading an universal binary that will work natively on both Intel and Apple Silicon machines.
- Also note that FPC 3.2.2 together with Lazarus 2.2.x (the above version) is listed as *Compatible* (green) for Apple Silicon M1/M2 on Big Sur and Monterey.